# Matlab 2013a installation error on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: matlab

after 83 percent installation it gives error

The following error was detected while installing sl3d_glnxa64:  archive is not a ZIP archive  Would you like to retry installing sl3d_glnxa64? If you press No, the installer will exit without completing the installation.

Comment: "More information can be found at /tmp/mathworks_root.log" did not seem important to look at and include in the question?

Answer (score 3):

I got the exact same problem. The quick fix is to deselect "Simulink 3D Animation Toolbox" during intallation provided that you don't need it.

From: [Matlab install error: Simulink 3D Animation Toolbox](http://wyldeplayground.net/matlab-install-error-simulink-3d-animation-toolbox/)

Comment: I also ran into the error exactly at 83%, and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is an error that occurs when you run out of space in /tmp/. /tmp/ is used to temporary store the extracted files. Increase it and it will install.

[From the matlab forums](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98745).

Besides that: `-tmpdir` is an option that you can use with the `.install` command to have it use another directory.

Comment: how to use another directory I'm new to it so please don't mind

Comment: the link does not have a solution

Comment: you can reboot to auto clean /tmp/ and try to install again